# Angular 2 - building "dist" for production using "npm", and not "ng build -prod"

Tags: node.js, angular, build, npm, production-environment

I have a project that I am building and running with `npm start` instead of `ng serve`. I am an angular 2 beginner, so I don't know how to build this project for production, in order to have the `dist/` folder with pure javascript/html/css in it. For `ng init` - created angular 2 apps, if I use `ng` command, I can just do `ng build --prod` when work is done and the `dist` folder is created. If I use `ng build --prod` on this project, angular is offering me to overwrite some of my files (app.module.ts, app.component.ts, etc....) which I don't want overwritten. There are routing things inside and I don't want to change them. How can I have the production version of this app (ie. the dist/ folder) without using the `ng build --prod` command? Angular-cli version is:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
```

Comment: Which version of angular CLI are you using ? Also, you said multiple time 'ng build -prod' but the correct command is 'ng build --prod'.

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
I edited the question to have two dashes for prod parameter.

Comment: Also, I DON'T WANT TO USE angular-cli for build process, but NPM.

Comment: Can I ask you why you don't wanna use it ?

Comment: Also npm start == ng serve. So you are using the CLI. You should upgrade it to the latest version. Please refer to this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: I don't want to use it because of the reason explained in the original question.

Comment: It should not do that, that's why we recommended you to upgrade the CLI to the latest version.

Comment: Upgrading as we speak.

Comment: Make sure to follow the instructions in the answer bellow. Otherwise you can and up breaking your project. Also I recommend you to back up your 'src' folder before updating.

Comment: I meant to say that I am independent in terms of development.

Comment: I did everything you said and it didn't work and ng build --prod is still trying to overwrite it.

Comment: I highly recommend Webpack. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use @angular/cli instead of angular-cli :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

when I use `ng build --prod` there is no such a problem.

Comment: what is the difference between @angular/cli and angular-cli?

Comment: angular-cli is an old version, @angular/cli is newer

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instructions to update your CLI to the latest version:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli